# Batch - Rename multiple files to sequential numbers while maintaining part of the original file name

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple files that need to be renamed sequentially. Below are some examples of the file names I might get.

```
vendorA050123.csv
vendorA050223.csv
vendorA050323.csv
vendorB050123.csv
vendorB050223.csv
vendorB050323.csv
```

I would want the batch file to rename them

```
vendorA1.csv 
vendorA2.csv 
vendorA3.csv 
vendorB1.csv 
vendorB2.csv 
vendorB3.csv
```

I had a code from a previous file but it renames all the files the same.

```bash
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
For %%x in (*.*) do (
  echo "%%x"|findstr /L "VendorA">nul
  if errorlevel 1 (echo skip %%x) else (
    ren %%x VendorA1.csv
  )
)
```

I found a code online that sequentially renames files but they will get rid of the original file name, the files need to have the name of the vendor name.

```bash
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set/a fileNum = 1

for %%f in (*.csv) do (
  ren %%~nf%%~xf !fileNum!%%~xf
  set/a fileNum += 1
)
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the directories and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "lastname=:"

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN (
 'dir /b /a-d /on "%sourcedir%\*.csv" '
 ) DO (
 SET "filename=%%~ne"
 SET /a oldnum=0
 SET /a oldnum=1!filename:~-6! 2>NUL
 IF !oldnum! neq 0 (
  SET "vendor=!filename:~0,-6!"
  SET "serial="
  FOR /L %%y IN (1,1,999) DO IF NOT DEFINED serial IF NOT EXIST "%sourcedir%\!vendor!%%y%%~xe" SET /a serial=%%y
  REN "%sourcedir%\%%e" "!vendor!!serial!%%~xe"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

I'm assuming that the filenames you want to change end with 6 digits.

First, the `dir` creates a list of the filenames (only) in memory. I added the `/on` switch as my test drive is a FAT32. It's not necessary if the drive is NTFS.

That list is then assigned sequentially to `%%e`

Find the filename part, set `oldnum` to zero and then assign `1`+the last 6 characters of the filename to `oldnum` using `set /a`.

If the last 6 characters are not all-numeric, then an error will occur (suppressed by the `2>nul`) and `oldnum` will remain `0`.

So if `oldnum` is now non-zero, get the vendor (all bar the last 6 chars of the filename) and set `serial` to *undefined*.

Now check for filenames `vendor.%%y`, and set `serial` to the first name that does not exist.

Glue the bits together and rename the file.

To pick ONLY a particular vendor, change

```
 'dir /b /a-d /on "%sourcedir%\*.csv" '
```

to

```
 'dir /b /a-d /on "%sourcedir%\%~1.csv" '
```

then run as

*thisbatchname* "vendor"

where the quotes are not required unless the vendor id contains spaces or some other non-alphameric symbols.

Using `*.csv` as originally posted, all vendors will be processed.

Comment: Hello Magoo, Thanks for this, so I would just need to replicate this for basically VendorA and VendorB right? I just want to make sure that it picks up only VendorA files and not VendorB files.